# Bootstrap form does not work on phone version

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form and when I want to enter data on desktop version it works fine but when I want to enter data to the form in Mobile version I cannot enter anything into the fields. It does not let me to enter any information to the fields.

```
<div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10
     col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 mform mainCont">

      <form    action="buynow.php" method="post"  class="form"  >

        <div class='form-row'>
          <div class='col-xs-12 form-group '>
            <label class='control-label'>First Name</label>
            <input name="FName" class='form-control'  type='text'>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class='form-row'>
          <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
            <label class='control-label'>Last Name</label>
            <input  name="LName"class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class='form-row'>
          <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
            <label class='control-label'>Email</label>
            <input name="EM"  class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class='form-row'>
          <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
            <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label>
            <input name="NONCard"  class='form-control' size='4'  type='text'>
          </div>
```

Comment: Did you close the  `</form> ` ?

Comment: yes I did just forgot to put it here

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some issues on your floating elements, their parents aren't wrapping them, but I'm not so sure.

```
.form-inline form-control {
  display:block;
}

.form-inline form-control:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.form-inline .col-lg-12 {
  clear:both;
}
```